# Having a regex working for both Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, regex, cross-browser

We encountered some problems in Safari browsers with the regex that we are using. This was the regex:

`/(?<=type: ).*./g`

Safari could not handle this and therefore we changed it to this:

`/(?:)(type: ).*./g`

The problem with this is that now for Chrome it does not return the right value back. Is there a way to have a regex working for both Chrome and Safari with the same response. So desired response is:

```
BUSINESS
ACC
false
```

**Code Example**

```js
const query = "{\n          testObject(testInput : {\n            id: \"id-13\",\n            life: ACC,\n            type: BUSINESS,\n            promo: [],\n            isvalid: false\n          })}\n      }"

const pattern = /\(([^)]+)\)/g;
const result = query.match(pattern) ? query.match(pattern).map((v) => v.trim().replace(/^\(|\)$/g, ''))[0] : null;

/* DOES NOT WORK IN SAFARI */
const queryTypePattern = /(?<=type: ).*./g;
const queryLifePattern = /(?<=life: ).*./g;
const queryIsValidPattern = /(?<=isvalid: ).*./g;

const queryType = result.match(queryTypePattern) ? result.match(queryTypePattern).map((v) => v.trim().replace(',', ''))[0] : null;
const queryLife = result.match(queryLifePattern) ? result.match(queryLifePattern).map((v) => v.trim().replace(',', ''))[0] : null;
const queryIsValid = result.match(queryIsValidPattern) ? result.match(queryIsValidPattern).map((v) => v.trim().replace(',', ''))[0] : null;

console.log('#### RETURNS THE CORRECT OUTPUT IN CHROME: ');
console.log(queryType);
console.log(queryLife);
console.log(queryIsValid);


/* WORKS IN SAFARI */
const queryTypePattern2 = /(?:type: ).*./g;
const queryLifePattern2 = /(?:life: ).*./g;
const queryIsValidPattern2 = /(?:isvalid: ).*./g;

const queryType2 = result.match(queryTypePattern2) ? result.match(queryTypePattern2).map((v) => v.trim().replace(',', ''))[0] : null;
const queryLife2 = result.match(queryLifePattern2) ? result.match(queryLifePattern2).map((v) => v.trim().replace(',', ''))[0] : null;
const queryIsValid2 = result.match(queryIsValidPattern2) ? result.match(queryIsValidPattern2).map((v) => v.trim().replace(',', ''))[0] : null;

console.log('#### RETURNS THE INCORRECT OUTPUT IN CHROME: ');
console.log(queryType2);
console.log(queryLife2);
console.log(queryIsValid2);
```

Comment: Just to make it more clear.. 1. there's a reason why you used a dot in the end of your regex?; 2. is the string to parse always having newlines after each key-value property pair? 3. since the positive lookbehind is not supported on safari as you stated, isn't better to just do something like `.match(/type:\s(?<value>.*)/img);` so that dot won't match newline and you'll just grab anything following the given property name (+space)? as for the latest suggestion.. you won't need to do that trim stuff you do on the match result but just grab the capturing group (named value).

Comment: maybe next time take the time to answers questions asked in comments instead of ignoring them and wasting people's time. Don't expect people to just go straight and answer without first trying to better understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture `.*` and match without the global flag.

```
/(?:type: )(.*)/
```

In this way, it returns an array of two strings:

- full matched value (ex: `type: BUSINESS`)
- captured group (ex: `BUSINESS`)

We need the second one.

```js
const query = "{\n          testObject(testInput : {\n            id: \"id-13\",\n            life: ACC,\n            type: BUSINESS,\n            promo: [],\n            isvalid: false\n          })}\n      }"

const pattern = /\(([^)]+)\)/g;
const result = query.match(pattern) ? query.match(pattern).map((v) => v.trim().replace(/^\(|\)$/g, ''))[0] : null;

const queryTypePattern2 = /(?:type: )(.*)/;
const queryLifePattern2 = /(?:life: )(.*)/;
const queryIsValidPattern2 = /(?:isvalid: )(.*)/;

const queryType2 = result.match(queryTypePattern2) ? result.match(queryTypePattern2).map((v) => v.trim().replace(',', ''))[1] : null;
const queryLife2 = result.match(queryLifePattern2) ? result.match(queryLifePattern2).map((v) => v.trim().replace(',', ''))[1] : null;
const queryIsValid2 = result.match(queryIsValidPattern2) ? result.match(queryIsValidPattern2).map((v) => v.trim().replace(',', ''))[1] : null;

console.log(queryType2);
console.log(queryLife2);
console.log(queryIsValid2);
```

As the solution does not contain lookbehind, it will work for both browsers.

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes that you have a correct regex for Chrome and another correct regex for Safari, but the regex which is correct for one browser is incorrect in the other.

[Here](https://codepedia.info/detect-browser-in-javascript) you have a function which detects the browser:

```
function fnBrowserDetect(){
                 
         let userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
         let browserName;
         
         if(userAgent.match(/chrome|chromium|crios/i)){
             browserName = "chrome";
           }else if(userAgent.match(/firefox|fxios/i)){
             browserName = "firefox";
           }  else if(userAgent.match(/safari/i)){
             browserName = "safari";
           }else if(userAgent.match(/opr\//i)){
             browserName = "opera";
           } else if(userAgent.match(/edg/i)){
             browserName = "edge";
           }else{
             browserName="No browser detection";
           }
         
          document.querySelector("h1").innerText="You are using "+ browserName +" browser";         
  }
```

Now, let's implement a function that uses the browser-detector function above:

```
function getRegex() {
     switch (fnBrowserDetect()) {
         case "safari": return "yoursafariregex";
         case "chrome": return "yourchromeregex";
         /* Logic for other browsers if you want to support them*/
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this approach! This is a very safe approach to target multiple browsers. In the end we went for the other approach because it was just for fixing our mocking server for local development.

Comment: @Rotan075 happy to help! Basically this is a general approach you might take whenever you face incompatible behaviors between browsers.